# Jquery Nth-Child question

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

How, using Nth-Child could I add a class to every red box?

[alt text http://www.eirestudio.net/hosting-files/dd.png](http://www.eirestudio.net/hosting-files/dd.png)

**I have tried using:**

```
$('#mainnav li ul li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('yes');
```

**Markup:**

```
<ul>
      <li><a href="">SUUB</a></li>
      <li><a href="">SUUB</a></li>
      <li><a href="">SUUB</a></li>
      <li><a href="">SUUB</a></li>
      <li><a href="">SUUB</a></li>
      <li><a href="">SUUB</a></li>
      <li><a href="">SUUB</a></li>
      <li><a href="">SUUB</a></li>
      <li><a href="">SUUB</a></li>
      <li><a href="">SUUB</a></li>
      <li><a href="">SUUB</a></li>
      <li><a href="">SUUB</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Showing us the markup would be way more helpful than showing us how it displays.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that...in fact, check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G6kSV/ . Seems to be working correctly -- perhaps you're having a problem with something other than nth-child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one will put the `yes` class on all LIs, except for the first one and then every third:

```
$('#mainnav li ul li:not(:nth-child(3n+1))').addClass('yes');
```

Answer (score 1):

As one solution, you can apply the class to all items and remove it from every third...

```
$('#mainnav ul li').addClass('yes').parent().find(':nth-child(3n)').removeClass('yes');​​​​
```

Comment: This will add the `yes` class to the first two columns.